# how does tensorflow save and restore model?

Tags: python, model, save, tensorflow, restore

First, I know how to use tensorflow to save and restore a model, just like the tutorial:

```
import tensorflow as tf
v1 = tf.Variable(1.32, name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(1.33, name="v2")

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print v2.eval(sess)
    save_path="model.ckpt"
    saver.save(sess,save_path)
    saver.restore(sess, save_path)
    print("Model restored.")
```

As you can see, it works well. Then I wrote two model in single file `model_save.py` just like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf 
v1 = tf.Variable(66, name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(77, name="v2")

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print 'v2', v2.eval(sess)
    save_path = "model_v/model.ckpt"
    saver.save(sess, save_path)
    print "ModelV saved."
    saver.restore(sess, save_path)
    print "ModelV restored."
    print 'v2', v2.eval(sess)

p1 = tf.Variable(88, name="p1")
p2 = tf.Variable(99, name="p2")

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print 'p2',p2.eval(sess)
    save_path = "model_p/model.ckpt"
    saver.save(sess, save_path)
    print "ModelP saved."
    saver.restore(sess, save_path)
    print "ModelP restored."
    print 'p2', p2.eval(sess)
```

It works well too! Then I wrote a `model.py` file in which I wrapped `p` and `v` in two models, which are called `ModelP` and `ModelV`, just like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf

class ModelV():

    def __init__(self):

        self.v1 = tf.Variable(66, name="v1")
        self.v2 = tf.Variable(77, name="v2")
        self.save_path = "model_v/model.ckpt"
        self.init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
        self.sess = tf.Session()

    def train(self):
        self.sess.run(self.init)
        print 'v2', self.v2.eval(self.sess)

        self.saver.save(self.sess, self.save_path)
        print "ModelV saved."

    def predict(self):
        self.saver.restore(self.sess, self.save_path)
        print "ModelV restored."
        print 'v2', self.v2.eval(self.sess)

class ModelP():

    def __init__(self):

        self.p1 = tf.Variable(88, name="p1")
        self.p2 = tf.Variable(99, name="p2")
        self.save_path = "model_p/model.ckpt"
        self.init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
        self.sess = tf.Session()

    def train(self):
        self.sess.run(self.init)
        print 'p2', self.p2.eval(self.sess)

        self.saver.save(self.sess, self.save_path)
        print "ModelP saved."

    def predict(self):
        self.saver.restore(self.sess, self.save_path)
        print "ModelP restored."
        print 'p2', self.p2.eval(self.sess)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = ModelV()
    p = ModelP()
    #v.train()
    v.predict()
    #p.train()
    p.predict()
```

Then I directly use model saved by `model_save.py`, it works well again. 
[image: 1]
Now I will throw my question, I split `ModelP` and `ModelV` in two files:

ModelV.py

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf

class ModelV():

    def __init__(self):

        self.v1 = tf.Variable(66, name="v1")
        self.v2 = tf.Variable(77, name="v2")
        self.save_path = "model_v/model.ckpt"
        self.init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
        self.sess = tf.Session()

    def train(self):
        self.sess.run(self.init)
        print 'v2', self.v2.eval(self.sess)

        self.saver.save(self.sess, self.save_path)
        print "ModelV saved."

    def predict(self):
        self.saver.restore(self.sess, self.save_path)
        print "ModelV restored."
        print 'v2', self.v2.eval(self.sess)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = ModelV()
    v.train()
    v.predict()
```

ModelP.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf

class ModelP():

    def __init__(self):

        self.p1 = tf.Variable(88, name="p1")
        self.p2 = tf.Variable(99, name="p2")
        self.save_path = "model_p/model.ckpt"
        self.init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
        self.sess = tf.Session()

    def train(self):
        self.sess.run(self.init)
        print 'p2', self.p2.eval(self.sess)

        self.saver.save(self.sess, self.save_path)
        print "ModelP saved."

    def predict(self):
        self.saver.restore(self.sess, self.save_path)
        print "ModelP restored."
        print 'p2', self.p2.eval(self.sess)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = ModelP()
    p.train()
    p.predict()
```

Then i run following, first ModelV.py and then ModelP.py,then model.py; 
[image: 2]
see what happend, Error happend! Following is my error:

```
ModelV restored.
v2 77
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key v2 not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key v1 not found in checkpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model.py", line 58, in <module>
    p.predict()
File "model.py", line 47, in predict
    self.saver.restore(self.sess, self.save_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1388, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key v2 not found in checkpoint
    [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_3 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_3/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_3/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op u'save_1/RestoreV2_3', defined at:
File "model.py", line 54, in <module>
    p = ModelP()
File "model.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1000, in __init__
    self.build()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1030, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 624, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 361, in _AddRestoreOps
    tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 200, in restore_op
    [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 441, in restore_v2
    dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key v2 not found in checkpoint
    [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_3 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_3/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_3/shape_and_slices)]]
```

This is just an example which I use to test because I have another project in which I wrote two models in one file, and each model is an object, each provides a predict and train interface, same error happened. It sames tensorflow just search first model's variables in another model's checkpoint file. It mix up, but they are in two models! Thanks for giving me some help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow: Restoring variables from from multiple checkpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733917/tensorflow-restoring-variables-from-from-multiple-checkpoints)